# What is the best way to share variables across Phaser3 class methods?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to find a clean, readable way to manage variables across functions in a Phaser Class but for various reasons I am unsatisfied with the solutions I've found.

What I am aware is avaiable:

**Global Variables**

I'm not very fond of this implementation for the possibility of variables being accessible by other files.

```
var heroes = [];

var play = new Phaser.Class({
    Extends: Phaser.Scene,

    initialize: function(){
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, {key: 'play'});
    },
    create: function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            heroes.add(new Hero())
        }
    },
    update: function(){
        if(!heroes.length){
            heroes.add(new Hero())
        }

        heroes.forEach(function(hero){
            if(hero.hp <= 0){
                hero.destroy();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**DataManager class (implemented as registry)**

I prefer this since it's more controlled but to me DataManager feels like it's intended for configs, not as a means to process/share data between class methods; also accessing and updating variables feels very heavy-handed with a specific service to get and set its values.

```
var play = new Phaser.Class({
    Extends: Phaser.Scene,

    initialize: function(){
        this.registry.set('heroes', []);
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, {key: 'play'});
    },
    create: function () {
        var heroes = this.registry.get('heroes');

        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            heroes.add(new Hero())
        }

        this.registry.set('heroes', heroes);
    },
    update: function(){
        var heroes = this.registry.get('heroes');

        if(!heroes.length){
            heroes.add(new Hero())
        }

        heroes.forEach(function(hero){
            if(hero.hp <= 0){
                hero.destroy();
            }
        });

        this.registry.set('heroes', heroes);
    }
});
```

**Using 'this'**

This feels the cleanest way to me so far since this refers to the class object and it's easy enough to update and retrieve values BUT in this context 'this' is shared with some internal Phaser specific variables which I want to separate my variables from. Besides namespacing with this are there any alternative solutions?

[image]

```
var play = new Phaser.Class({
    Extends: Phaser.Scene,

    initialize: function(){
        this.heroes = [];
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, {key: 'play'});
    },
    create: function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            this.heroes.add(new Hero())
        }
    },
    update: function(){
        if(!heroes.length){
            this.heroes.add(new Hero())
        }

        this.heroes.forEach(function(hero){
            if(hero.hp <= 0){
                hero.destroy();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: good question! What about a global between classes?

Comment: @Ventoh If I were to be sharing variables across different classes (as opposed to methods within a class) then yes I would use a single global (probably namespaced by class name). However I'm trying to avoid accidentally giving visibility of a class's inner workings to other classes.   My goal is to make each individual class share it's variables across its own methods without that variable belonging to a different object (e.g. this.heroes belongs to an object which already has other props on it. this.A, this.B, this.Heroes, this.C.   The self-invoking seems to satisfy all that for me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised another way to do it is using a self-invoking function:

In this example heroes will be scoped to the function and also shouldn't pollute the return object;

```
var play = new Phaser.Class(function(){
    var heroes = [];

    return {
    Extends: Phaser.Scene,

    initialize: function(){
        heroes = [];
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, {key: 'play'});
    },
    create: function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            heroes.add(new Hero())
        }
    },
    update: function(){
        if(!heroes.length){
            heroes.add(new Hero())
        }

        heroes.forEach(function(hero){
            if(hero.hp <= 0){
                hero.destroy();
            }
        });
    }
}}());
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried to pass some global data between scenes and found the following. Each scene has its own ref to the global registry. Here is the quote from documentation:

> This is a game-wide instance of the Data Manager, allowing you to exchange data between Scenes via a universal and shared point. 
>  In the default set-up you can access this from within a Scene via the `this.registry` property.

https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Data.DataManager.html
Here is the doc with the detailed description of the class. Tried this in a recent game - it's very convenient in use.

Comment: `this.registry` worked for me! It can be used like this: `this.registry.set('playerData', {lives: 0, deaths: 0, health: 100})` and can then be retrieved like this: `this.registry.get('playerData')`

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and most readable way in my opinion would be using proper classes (and not instances of `Phaser.Class`). You can always extend a Phaser class that you need (like here with `Phaser.Scene`).

TypeScript:

```
class Play extends Phaser.Scene {
    private heroes: Hero[] = [];

    private create(): void {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.heroes.push(new Hero());
        }
    }

    private update(): void {
        if (!this.heroes.length) {
            this.heroes.push(new Hero());
        }

        this.heroes.forEach((hero) => {
            if (hero.hp <= 0) {
                hero.destroy();
            }
        });
    }

    public initialize(): void {
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'play' });
    }
}
```

ES6 (same, except for type declarations and access modifiers):

```
class Play extends Phaser.Scene {
    heroes = [];

    create() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.heroes.push(new Hero());
        }
    }

    update() {
        if (!this.heroes.length) {
            this.heroes.push(new Hero());
        }

        this.heroes.forEach((hero) => {
            if (hero.hp <= 0) {
                hero.destroy();
            }
        });
    }

    initialize() {
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'play' });
    }
}
```

If you're for some reason stuck to ES5, then your last suggestion might be your best bet.

Comment: I'm not restricted to ES5 exactly, my friend and I just don't have as much experience with ES6.
That said, I have thought of an ES5 solution that I like, though I will try this first and compare as it certainly reads better :)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at TypeScript. Yes, it adds a little bit of overhead (you can't use your code directly and you have to have a build step, that's also the case with ES6 - although most current browsers are directly compatible, you'll see a lot of projects targeting ES5 by using Babel for example), but it saves a lot of troubles once your project starts to grow.

Comment: Phaser3 appears to not have the TS definitions complete yet so I've tried to just make it work with ES6.   
Despite following this tutorial: http://codetuto.com/2018/02/getting-started-phaser-3-es6-create-boomdots-game/
It seems the sourcemaps don't work (probably my lack of experience with webpack) which makes debugging somewhat difficult.
That aside, if I were using "this." it looks my variables would still share the same scope as the Phaser lib variables, so I think I'll be sticking with the ES5 solution for thanks.
We might come back to ES6 again after we're more familiar with Phaser.